# Convert FloatTensor to HalfTensor in Pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, tensor, dtype

I am using a pretrained model from transformers which expects input type to be `torch.HalfTensor`. However, I have input of type `torch.FloatTensor`. How to convert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`torch.Tensor.half()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.half.html) should do:

```py
torch.rand(3,3).half()
# tensor([[0.1456, 0.0580, 0.9277],
#        [0.3318, 0.1979, 0.6670],
#        [0.5391, 0.2012, 0.2445]], # dtype=torch.float16)
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to the answer of *Learning is a mess*: There are several ways to convert a tensor from float to half

```
import torch

t_f = torch.FloatTensor(3, 2) 
print(t_f.dtype)  # torch.float32

# all t_hx are of type torch.float16
t_h1 = t_f.half() # works for cpu and  gpu tensors
t_h2 = t_f.type(torch.HalfTensor)  # only for cpu tensors, use torch.cuda.HalfTensor for gpu tensor 
t_h3 = t_f.to(torch.half)  # .to() works also on models
```

See the [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html) for more info on torch tensor data types.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote... and also for accepting the answer. Though, I actually prefer the suggestion of Learning-is-a-mess to  use `tensor.half()` to the type conversion with `tensor.type(new_type)`. See my edited answer.